# MonoTouch navigate back (swipe right)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have this [Swipe](https://gist.github.com/2884348) extension method:

```
View.Swipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right).Event += (s, r) =>
        View.RemoveFromSuperview();
```

The `View.RemoveFromSuperview()` makes the screen go blank.  I'm trying to go back to the previous view, what is the command/method I need to call for that?

I pushed the current view with:

```
AppDelegate.Current.NavController.PushViewController(new SingleIssueController(Item), true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PopViewController, if this is happening in the "SingleIssueController", pass the "AppDelegate.Current.NavController" as a parameter, like this:

```
var nav = AppDelegate.Current.NavController;
nav.PushViewController (new SingleIssueController (Item, nav));
```

Then in your SingleIssueController you can attach to the event and pop like this:

```
View.Swipe (....).Event += (s,r) => nav.PopViewControllerAnimated (true);
```

Comment: There is no `PopViewController()`. I'm testing out `PopViewControllerAnimated()`